# Loaded two datasets into python and want to take a column from second dataset and put into first dataset

Tags: python, dataframe

[enter image description here][1][enter image description here][2]I wanted to add a column from the second data set into the first dataset. Basically I loaded two datasets in python and wanted to add the age column from the second dataset, and put it as a column for the first dataset, which doesnt have an age column. My end goal is for the first dataset without the age column, to now have the age column that the second dataset has. Is there a way to do this? I got an error for my code when I tried to use the merge function. What should I do?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100) #2443 
df= pd.read_csv('genedata.csv')
df

df1=pd.read_csv('traits.csv')
df1

df2= pd.merge(df,df1)
```

**MergeError**: `No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False`

Comment: can you provide more info on the columns on which merge is possible?

Comment: Based on the error message, there is no common column from these to datasets. to merge atleast you need a column which is available in both datasets. if it has unique values that will be the best.

Comment: If they don't have common columns, what should I do?

Comment: without a common column, merging is not possible. otherwise you have to store the column from df1 as a list and assign to df. if possible can you please share a sample data.. **df.head()**

Comment: I added the two images for the two datasets

Comment: good to see the datasets. what should be your output? can you please add it by manually

Comment: I just want the age column from the second dataset inserted as a column into the first dataset, like right next to the sample ID column

Comment: ok.. based on what condition? is the length of the both datasets are same?

Comment: no, the length of the datasets aren't the same. Im not sure what you mean by condition? Maybe I could do what you said and store the column as a list and then add it to the first dataset?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) ... Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

short answer:

```
df = pd.read_csv('genedata.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv('traits.csv')

df['age'] = df1['age_column_from_second_source']
```

**note** this assumes your dataframe sizes are equal in length